# Convert all filenames to lowercase

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I recursively change the case of files and folders under bash](https://serverfault.com/questions/88442/how-can-i-recursively-change-the-case-of-files-and-folders-under-bash)

How can I convert all file names to lowercase in a directory and its subdirectories, using a command or batch script?

Comment: You mention "bash" and "cmd", which are two different environments. Which one is it? I'm assuming Bash?

Comment: By cmd I mean "command line" (terminal)

Comment: Ah. `cmd` usually refers to the Windows command-prompt.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/88442/how-can-i-recursively-change-the-case-of-files-and-folders-under-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also want to rename the folder, use this [script](http://www.linuxweblog.com/node/306).

Answer (score 1):

First off, `tr` can be used to translate text.  `tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` will translate all upper case characters from stdin into lower case in stdout.  So it's just a matter of working that into your script...

```
for $FILE in `find . -name [whatever] -print`
    do mv $FILE `echo $FILE | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`
done
```

This is pretty ugly, and it spits out errors if the file name is already lower case.  (because you try to move it onto itself)  But it should do the job.  Be sure to mod up whomever posts a cleaned up version.

Comment: This fails for files that have spaces in their names.

Comment: This also fails for me if a subfolder contains capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

This is mild variation to `Christopher`'s answer,

```
find . -type f > files.txt
IFS="
";
for f in $(cat files.txt);
do
    mv $f $(echo $f | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])
done
```

If you want to work on directories rather than files use,

```
find . -type d > dirs.txt
```